# I cannot install matplotlib using "Pip install matplotlib" command

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I am using python 3.5.0 where "pip intall python" command for installing "Matplotlib" is not working. Here is the error that i get:

```
C:\>pip install matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 57
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+sys.stderr.write%28f%22ERROR%3A+%7Bexc%7D%22%29

Answer (score 0):

type `pip install matplotlib` into cmd

if that doesn't work, [ensure ...\python\scripts\ folder is in your PATH](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/)

1. open your scripts folder and ensure there is a pip.exe in there
2. try this in CMD

   cd c:\users\blah\blah\Python\Scripts
   .\pip.exe install matplotlib

Comment: python scripts folder is in my Path still it's not working

Comment: open your scripts folder and ensure there is a pip.exe in there

try this in CMD:

cd c:\users\blah\blah\Python\Scripts  ------new_line-----
.\pip.exe install matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

You should try: `python -m pip install matplotlib` in a cmd prompt (run as admin).

Answer (score 0):

I tried all solutions that i got on stackoverflow but nothing seemed to be working for python 3.5.0, indeed the problem was resolved when i updated my python version to the latest release of python 3.9.7

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to upgrade pip first using following command in cmd as admin:

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
> then try this command:
> pip install matplotlib